# How to generate Navigation Drawer item's dynamically from xml?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer, navigationview

I prepared 2 xml menu files and placed inside my **res/menu** folder.

**menu_beforeLogin.xml** will be displayed if the user didn't logged in. 
After they logged in, the menu item will changed to **menu_afterLogin.xml**.

I tried to called **InflateMenu()** in my **onResume()** method, but it ends up with keep adding the items from xml file whenever **onResume()** is invoked instead of removing/regenerate the menu list.

I would prefer to check user is logged in or not in **onResume()** method.

> What is the proper way to change Navigation Drawer's list dynamically
>   ?

**MainActivity.cs**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
    mDrawer = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.navigation_drawer);
    ...
}

protected override void OnResume ()
{
    base.OnResume ();
    string token = pref.GetString (Constant.PREF_TOKEN, "");
    mDrawer.InflateMenu ( (token == "") ? Resource.Menu.menu_drawer_notLoggedIn : Resource.Menu.menu_drawer);           
    mDrawer.Invalidate ();
    ...
}
```

**layout/main.axml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    ...
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**res/menu/menu_beforeLogin.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_login"
        android:title="@string/navigation_login" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notice"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_notice"
        android:title="@string/navigation_notice" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contactUs"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_contactUs"
        android:title="@string/navigation_contactUs" />
</menu>
```

**res/menu/menu_afterLogin.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notice"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_notice"
        android:title="@string/navigation_notice" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_profile"
        android:title="@string/navigation_profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_contactUs"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_contactUs"
        android:title="@string/navigation_contactUs" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/navigation_logout"
        android:title="@string/navigation_logout" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to clear your menu item before inflating new menu.

> mDrawer.Menu.Clear ();